# how to make search using javascript and ajax

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I'm trying to make a search, at first I get data from json file and than searching, but the problem is the json file is successfully loaded but the search doesn't work and i can't find a mistake i think in this line of code something wrong if (key.search(myExp) != -1)
js file:

```
$(function() {

    var searchField = document.getElementById("search");
    var fieldVal = searchField.value;
    var myExp = new RegExp(fieldVal, 'i');

    search.onkeyup = function() {

        var request;
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("GET", "data.json");

        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
                var info = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                var output = "";

                for (var i = 0; i <= info.links.length; i++) {
                    for (key in info.links[i]) {
                        if (info.links[i].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                            if (key.search(myExp) != -1) {
                                output += "<p>" + key + "</p>";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                var update = document.getElementById("result");
                update.innerHTML = output;
            }
        };
        request.send();
    };
});
```

json file:

```
{
    "full_name" : "dima",
    "links" : [
            { "blog"     : "http://iviewsource.com" },
            { "facebook" : "http://facebook.com/iviewsource" },
            { "podcast"  : "http://feeds.feedburner.com/authoredcontent" },
            { "twitter"  : "http://twitter.com/planetoftheweb" },
            { "youtube"  : "http://www.youtube.com/planetoftheweb" }
        ]
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? What should be the output?

Comment: blog, facebook, twitter but if i press "face" only facebook have to stay visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `fieldVal` and `myExp` are being set only once at the time of page load. For your desired output, you will need to update the regex before every check or on every keyup to get the latest value typed in the input.

Try with the following code:

```
$(function() {
    var searchField = document.getElementById("search");
    var fieldVal = searchField.value;
    var myExp = new RegExp(fieldVal, 'i');

    search.onkeyup = function() {
        var request;
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("GET", "data.json");

        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
                var info = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                var output = "";

                /***** UPDATED CODE *****/
                // get value of searchField to update the regex as per the latest value
                var fieldVal = searchField.value;
                var myExp = new RegExp(fieldVal, 'i');
                /***** UPDATED CODE *****/

                for (var i = 0; i <= info.links.length; i++) {
                    for (key in info.links[i]) {
                        if (info.links[i].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                            if (key.search(myExp) != -1) {
                                output += "<p>" + key + "</p>";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                var update = document.getElementById("result");
                update.innerHTML = output;
            }
        };
        request.send();
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Without getting into the actual search code, I noticed you're referencing an undefined object when adding the onkeyup event. Your DOM element is on `searchField` object, but you add the event to an unexistent (in the provided context) `search` object.

Comment: should i write something like this if (info.links.search(myExp) != -1) ?

Comment: Oddly, `search` will refer to the DOM element with `id="search"`. This is a strange feature supported by most of the browsers. It is a horrible practice to follow but does work.